# DataContract/DataMember multiple elements in xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, datacontract

I have an XML like this:

```
<data>
    <foo>some value</foo>
    <result>...</result>
    <result>...</result>
    <result>...</result>
    ...
</data>
```

I would like to deserialize it with DataContract/DataMember..
I know how to handle the array/collection of results elements if they were embedded inside a parent object like:

```
    <data>
    <foo>some value</foo>
    <collectionOfResults>
            <result>...</result>
            <result>...</result>
            <result>...</result>
            ...
    </collectionOfResults>
    </data>
```

But I don't know how to do it without the embedding element. Do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to control the format of the XML, then you don't want to use the DataContractSerializer. Use the XML Serializer instead.

Comment: @Max: same issue. You can't control the format with the Data Contract Serializer - either to serialize or deserialze.