# Not show name with CollectionDataContract attribute

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, servicestack

I am currently implementing an API using ServiceStack, and I've run into an issue. The API spec that I've been given defines the XML packet that will be sent to the API. This spec is not able to be changed and is not controlled by myself.

The issue is that in the root element, there is a list of items like so:

```
<data>
    <id>0</id>
    <locationID>10</locationID>
    <cust>
       <id>0</id>
    </cust>
    <cust>
       <id>0</id>
    </cust>
    <cust>
       <id>0</id>
    </cust>
    <cust>
       <id>0</id>
    </cust>
</data>
```

I have implemented the spec and have it almost correct, however I can't figure out how to have the  elements repeating in the XML without a surrounding parent node.

As this is using ServiceStack I am using Data Contracts and have tried setting up the  element as a CollectionDataContract, however that wraps the elements in a  parent node.

I was wondering if it is possible to specify that the  parent element is not used or if it is possible to implement a plain List in the  node that contains the  nodes without the parent.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem possible. The issue is that the serializer used by ServiceStack utilizes DataContracts, and I cannot find a way to replace this with another serializer, most likely because then we wouldnt be able to use multiple formats. I am closing this as an exact duplicate as other questions have been asked which as similar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataContract/DataMember multiple elements in xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565481/datacontract-datamember-multiple-elements-in-xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the .NET's DataContract Xml Serializer that's used in ServiceStack. If you find an XmlSerializer that does support this you could register to use that instead with:

```
appHost.ContentTypeFilters.Register(ContentType.Xml, SerializeToStream, DeserializeFromStream);
```

Or register a custom contentType as seen in:
http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Northwind/vcard-format.htm

Personally in this case I would just return a serialized xml string. You can do this either:

- In the body of Service by just return a string (you can wrap it in HttpResult to also force the specific ContentType). Returning an XML string in your service will always return XML for all endpoints.
- By overriding OnAfterExecute in ServiceBase and transforming a strong-typed response DTO into an XML string for XML ContentType requests.
- Registering a [custom response filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters) (or [Filter Attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes))

e.g:

```
appHost.ResponseFilters.Add((req, res, dto) =>
{
    if (req.ResponseContentType == ContentType.Xml)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        DataDto dataDto = (DataDto)dto;
        sb.AppendLine("<data>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<id>{0}</id>",dataDto.Id);
        //... etc
        res.ContentType = ContentType.Xml;
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(res.OutputStream)) {
          sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
        res.Close();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up pushing back on the guys who wrote the spec (that will be consuming the web service) and forced them to wrap the <cust> nodes in a <customers> parent node. Made things a lot easier.